# json error 406 ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

В консоле выбивает ошибку 406, как решить проблему?

script.js

```
$("#registerform").on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.editForm);
    formData.append("userData", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/user/update.php',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function(json_response){
                    console.log(json_response.status);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error!');
                }

            });
});
```

update.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['userData'])){
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $full_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['full_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);


    require_once("connection.php");

    global $con;

    session_start();

    $response = array();

    if (checkSID()) {

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `usertbl` 
                           SET full_name='$full_name', email='$email', phone='$phone' 
                           WHERE id='$id'
                           ");

        $array = array(
            "status" => 200,
            "content" => "Данные успешно обновлены"
        );

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)){

            echo json_encode($array);

        } else {

            $array["status"] = 406;
            $array["content"] = "Ошибка";

            echo json_encode($array);

        }

    }


        function checkEmail($email)
        {

            if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $email)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    function checkSID () {


       return ($_SESSION["session_username"] !== "");
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, в update.php функция `mysqli_affected_rows()` возвращает 0, потому что запрос не изменил ни одной строки в таблице. Это может произойти, если строки с указанным в запросе полем id не существует. Я бы посоветовал вывести в браузер строку с запросом к базе и выполнить ее вручную / просмотреть таблицу и убедиться, что запрос выполняется правильно.

Например, можно написать так:

```
$queryString = "UPDATE `usertbl` 
    SET full_name='$full_name', 
        email='$email', 
        phone='$phone'
    WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $queryString);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 0){
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => '406',
            'content' => 'Запрос не затронул ни одной строки: ' . $queryString
        ));
}
```

а в script.js

```
console.log(json_response.status);
```

заменить на

```
console.log(json_response);
```

, чтобы вывести все, что отправил сервер, а не только код статуса.

Comment: И еще, не по теме вопроса, но не могу промолчать - я бы посоветовал почитать про SQL-инъекции и сформировать SQL-запрос правильно, а то и вовсе перейти с MySQLi на PDO.